# How to create a user with credentials in okta using python sdk

Tags: python, okta

Is there any way to create okta user with credentials using python

Creates a user without a recovery question & answer. The new user will immediately be able to login after activation with the assigned password. This flow is common when developing a custom user registration experience.

```
curl -v -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: SSWS ${api_token}" \
-d '{
  "profile": {
    "firstName": "Isaac",
    "lastName": "Brock",
    "email": "isaac.brock@example.com",
    "login": "isaac.brock@example.com",
    "mobilePhone": "555-415-1337"
  },
  "credentials": {
    "password" : { "value": "tlpWENT2m" }
  }
}' "https://${org}.okta.com/api/v1/users?activate=false"
```

This one is by using Curl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) in Python:

```
import requests

url = '{{org}}.okta.com/api/v1/users'

headers = {
  'accept': 'application/json',
  'authorization' : 'SSWS {{api_token}}',
  'content-type': 'application/json'
}

body = {
  'profile': {
    'firstName': 'Isaac',
    'lastName': 'Brock',
    'email': 'isaac@{{email_suffix}}',
    'login': 'isaac@{{email_suffix}}'
  },
  'credentials': {
    'password' : { 'value': '{{password}}' }
  }
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
# r.json
```

Using the [Okta Python SDK](https://github.com/okta/oktasdk-python), you need to create a `client` first, then call the `create_user()` method.

```
from okta import UsersClient
from okta.models.user import User

usersClient = UsersClient("https://{{org}}.okta.com", "{{api_token}}")

user = User(login='isaac@{{email_suffix}}',
            email='isaac@{{email_suffix}}',
            firstName='Isacc',
            lastName='Brock')

user = usersClient.create_user(user, activate=False)
```

Comment: Using the Python SDK here, no password is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Okta API reference guide for create user ([here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#create-user-with-password)), And Okta Python SDK docs for create user ([here](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-python#create-a-user)):

There are two options, that worked for me:

1. Pass data as dict:

```py
import asyncio
from okta.client import Client as OktaClient
from okta.models import User, UserProfile

config = {
    'orgUrl': 'https://your_domain.okta.com',
    'token': 'your_token'
}


async def main():
    async with OktaClient(config) as client:
        data = {
            "profile": {
                "firstName": "Omid",
                "lastName": "Raha",
                "email": "omid@example.com",
                "login": "omid@example.com",
                "mobilePhone": "{123}-{456}-{789}"
            },
            "credentials": {
                "password": {"value": "Password!123"}
            }
        }
        res = await client.create_user(data, {'activate': True, })
        print('user created. info: {}'.format(res))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

2. Or pass data as okta object model:

```py
import asyncio
from okta.client import Client as OktaClient
from okta import models

config = {
    'orgUrl': 'https://your_domain.okta.com',
    'token': 'your_token'
}

# Create Password
password = models.PasswordCredential({
    'value': 'Password!123'
})

# Create User Credentials
user_creds = models.UserCredentials({
    'password': password
})

# Create User Profile and CreateUser Request
user_profile = models.UserProfile()
user_profile.first_name = 'Omid'
user_profile.last_name = 'Raha'
user_profile.email = 'omid@example.com'
user_profile.login = 'omid@example.com'

create_user_request = models.CreateUserRequest({
    'credentials': user_creds,
    'profile': user_profile
})


async def main():
    async with OktaClient(config) as client:
        res = await client.create_user(create_user_request, {'activate': True, })
        print('User created, info: {}'.format(res))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Response (same for both methods):

```json
User created, info: 
({
    'embedded': None, 
    'links': None, 
    'activated': '2022-08-17T10:05:02.000Z', 
    'created': '2022-08-17T10:05:02.000Z', 
    'credentials': {
        'password': {'hash': None, 'hook': None, 'value': None}, 
        'provider': {'name': 'OKTA', 'type': <AuthenticationProviderType.OKTA: 'OKTA'>}, 
        'recovery_question': None
    }, 
    'id': '23d83739Ejdj', 
    'last_login': None, 
    'last_updated': '2022-08-17T10:05:02.000Z', 
    'password_changed': '2022-08-17T10:05:02.000Z', 
    'profile': {
        'city': None, 
        'costCenter': None, 
        'countryCode': None, 
        'department': None, 
        'displayName': None, 
        'division': None, 
        'email': 'omid@example.com', 
        'employeeNumber': None, 
        'firstName': 'Omid', 
        'honorificPrefix': None, 
        'honorificSuffix': None, 
        'lastName': 'Raha', 
        'locale': None, 
        'login': 'omid@example.com', 
        'manager': None, 
        'managerId': None, 'middleName': None, 
        'mobilePhone': '123-456-789', 
        'nickName': None, 'organization': None, 
        'postalAddress': None, 
        'preferredLanguage': None, 
        'primaryPhone': None, 'profileUrl': None, 
        'secondEmail': None, 'state': None, 
        'streetAddress': None, 
        'timezone': None, 'title': None, 
        'userType': None, 'zipCode': None
    }, 
    'status': <UserStatus.ACTIVE: 'ACTIVE'>, 
    'status_changed': '2022-08-17T10:05:02.000Z', 
    'transitioning_to_status': None, 
    'type': {
        'links': None, 
        'created': None, 
        'created_by': None, 
        'default': None, 
        'description': None, 
        'display_name': None, 
        'id': '83Dm32dje3', 
        'last_updated': None, 
        'last_updated_by': None, 
        'name': None
    }
}, 
    <okta.api_response.OktaAPIResponse object at 0x7fd5e286f130>, None
)
```